# UITableView is not appearing in iPhone

Tags: uitableview, swift4, xcode9.3

The following code is to display the UITableView for an e-wallet type app. But the tableview is not appearing.

```
 import UIKit
class walletViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var filterImageView: UIImageView!



    let imageList = ["user1","user2","user3"]

    let titleTist = ["John","Anna","Eva"]

    let userPaid = ["Last Paid $100","Last Paid $200","Last Paid $150"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return titleTist.count
    }


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! EwalletTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...

        cell.cellTitle.text = titleTist[indexPath.row]
        cell.userStatus.text = userPaid[indexPath.row]

        cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageList[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
This following code is about the cellview and the items present in it.
import UIKit

class EwalletTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {



    @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var UserName: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var UserPaidInfo: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func paidButton(_ sender: Any) {

    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What does these 2 screenshots indicate? In the 2nd one you are getting the `tableView` and in the 1st one you are not. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

replace following lines

```
cell.UserName.text = titleTist[indexPath.row]
cell.UserPaidInfo.text = userPaid[indexPath.row]
cell.userImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageList[indexPath.row])
```

with

```
cell.cellTitle.text = titleTist[indexPath.row]
cell.userStatus.text = userPaid[indexPath.row]
cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageList[indexPath.row])
```

Answer (score 0):

For tablview first you need to check this thing step by step

- Check you are giving number of row count is not zero
- Check Tableview Datasource method is being called or not?
- In Swift you must have to import UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource beside viewController

Answer (score 0):

There was some errors with the constraints. Its been fixed. And everything is fine. Thank you all.